# MKMapView inside Tab Bar and Navigtion Controller hides Google branding

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uikit, mkmapview, uitabbar

I just received the following message when submitting to the app store:

> In addition, the application displays
>   images provided by Google Maps without
>   the corresponding Google branding, we
>   cannot post this version to the App
>   Store

I have a TabBar with a NavigationController inside. The Navigation Controller loads the map in

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    // ...
}
```

This works, but the mapView ends below the tab bar, so the Google logo is not shown. To get the frame correctly I have to create it manually

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,370)];
    // ...
}
```

This works, but doesn't feel right. What is the right way to do it?

The main interface (TabBar + Navigation Controllers) is created in Interface Builder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This fixes the issue

```
mapView.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats fine. :p Similarly you could do:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    CGRect bounds = self.view.bounds;
    bounds.size.height -= 90; // i think the tab bar controller is 90
    mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:bounds];
    // ...
}
```

Comment: i do appologise 49 is the nav bar. Tab bar controller is 90 (well, i've done 90 just now and it works fine with google branding). :)

Comment: OK, but still doesn't feel right that I have to enter the dimensions to fit in standard controls already placed in Interface Builder

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be by

```
CGRect viewBounds = self.view.bounds;
viewBounds.size.height -= self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame.size.height + self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height;
```

This way you dont supply absolute numerical values.